# convert molfile to fasta

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I am working on bioinformatics project.

I want to convert MDL file (molfile - .mol) to FASTA file using python.

Can anyone tell me how can I do the same?

mol file structure : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#Molfile
fasta file structure : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Comment: Can you show a small example of input and desired output?

Comment: mol file structure : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file#Molfile  and   fasta file structure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Comment: I've googled that, but the fact of the matter is that if you [edit] the question with an example of conversion, the it will more likely be answered.

Comment: actually i thought any module may be available to do the same

Comment: Did you tried the Biopython module? I think they have this converters and parsers

Answer (score 1):

[RDKit](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/index.html) provides a function [`MolToFASTA(mol)`](http://www.rdkit.org/Python_Docs/rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles-module.html#MolToFASTA) which outputs the FASTA sequence for the input molecule.  Should go something like:

```
from rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles import MolFromMolFile, MolToFASTA

mol = MolFromMolFile("yourFile.mol")
fa = MolToFASTA(mol)
# write the fa string to file
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an example .mol file of a protein to test this with.